# Is there a logical puzzle that is solvable only by using the fact that "It is solvable"?

Tags: logic, puzzle

Suppose you are given some sort of puzzle and told that it is solvable, for example a game such as minesweeper adhering to certain rules. You've played it using logical decisions but have now come to a position where normally it would be impossible to proceed without guessing. However, when you use the fact that it has to be solvable, then you can eliminate one of the options because, were it that option, you would still have to guess somewhere, thus making the puzzle solvable.

I suspect the answer to this is no, and that using the fact that it is solvable would never let you proceed any further, but can someone give an explanation or even proof for it?

Comment: Concerning minesweeper , you have to guess at least once (at the beginning), but often this is enough to solve it. In Sudoku, I came across a technique using that the solution is unique (which allows to eliminate possibilities which would lead to a non-unique solution , if there is one at all).  Hope that is helpful.

Comment: [Is there a puzzle that is only solvable by assuming there is a unique solution?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/104738/32666)

Comment: I don't know minesweeper, but in general for your title concern "a logical puzzle that is solvable only by using the fact that It is solvable?", the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) is exactly important for your solvability (provability) concern. So if you've already known a statement is true as part of a theory, then you're bound to find a proof. However, for an arbitrary statement per incompleteness theorems, it maybe unprovable since in this case there's no such fact that it's part of a maximally consistent  theory (solvable) or not.